# Python: reverse of transferring image into list of pixels?

Tags: python, image

```
im = Image.open('segmentace_zkusebni_pi.jpg')
pixel = list(im.getdata())
```

gets me a list of RGB of every pixel in the image.
For my thesis (not programming, math) I need also to reverse this process, after I do some calculations with RGB values of the pixels. So I need to get the list of 3-elemental vectors (variable pixel) transfer into image. Is there any way? Thank you very much

Comment: You can create a new image object and use Pillow's [`putdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putdata) method with the modified pixels to store them there.

Comment: No, no, no! Please don't treat images as lists of separate objects representing pixels where every single one has its own memory and management and junk. It is sloooooow, inefficient and wasteful of memory. Use Numpy for vectorised, or OpenCV for SIMD-processing.

Comment: Also, once you treat images as lists, you lose the concept of neighbours for filtering etc. It's just a poor idea, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('segmentace_zkusebni_pi.jpg')
n = np.asarray(im)
shape = n.shape

pixel = list(im.getdata())
# pixel = n.reshape((shape[0]*shape[1], shape[2])).tolist()

# do your work, but make sure the image dimension is kept same
# preferably you should work with numpy array itself
..
..

im2 = Image.fromarray((np.array(pixel, dtype='uint8')).reshape(shape))
im2.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of `Image` class, store your new pixels there by using `putdata` and then save the new image using `save` method. The following is an example:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('segmentace_zkusebni_pi.jpg')
pixel = list(im.getdata())

# Pixel modification code
newPixel = modify(pixel)

newImg = Image.new('RGB', (im.size[0], im.size[1]))
newImg.putdata(newPixel)
newImg.save('segmentace_zkusebni_pi_new.jpg')
```

You can check Pillow's [Image docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/Image.html).